# Oracle SQL dynamic nr of FOR LOOP iterations

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop

I would like to run the FOR LOOP in Oracle based on a parameter that is dynamically populated. Please see, how the code could look like:

```
declare
    idx number := (select max(field_name) from table_name); 

begin    
    for i in 1..idx loop
        dbms_output.put_line (i);
    end loop;
end;
```

So basically if the `select max(field_name) from table_name` returns for example 10, the loop should be run 10 times (`for i in 1..10 loop`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `field_name` is an integer, you only need to fetch the max value in the right way:

```
declare
    idx number; 
begin    
    select max(field_name)
    into idx
    from table_name;
    if idx is not null then  -- to handle the case where the table is empty
        for i in 1..idx loop
            dbms_output.put_line (i);
        end loop;
    end if;
end;
```

or, without the `IF`:

```
declare
    idx number; 
begin    
    select nvl(max(field_name), 0)
    into idx
    from table_name;
    for i in 1..idx loop
        dbms_output.put_line (i);
    end loop;
end;
```